# Merging multiple TypeSafe Config files and resolving only after they are all merged

Tags: merge, typesafe-config

I am writing test code to validate a RESTful service.  I want to be able to point it at any of our different environments by simply changing an environment variable before executing the tests.

I want to be able to merge three different config files:

- `conf/env/default.conf` - the default configuration values
  for all environments
- `conf/env/<env>.conf` - the environment-specific
  values
- `application.conf` - the user's overrides of any of the
  above

The idea is that I don't want everything in a single config file, and run the risk of a bad edit causing configuration items to get lost.  So instead, keep them separate and give the user the ability to override them.

Here's where it gets tricky:  `default.conf` will include ${references} to things that are meant to be overridden in `<env>.conf`, and may be further overridden in `application.conf`.

I need to postpone resolving until all three are merged.  How do I do that?

Comment: I have given a thumbs up to John's answer and its worth referring [https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior](https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior) before starting to merge your configurations.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The answer is to use `ConfigFactory.parseResource()` in place of `ConfigFactory.load()`.

Here is the finished result

```
private lazy val defaultConfig     = ConfigFactory.parseResources("conf/env/default.conf")
private lazy val environmentConfig = ConfigFactory.parseResources("conf/env/" + env + ".conf" )
private lazy val userConfig        = ConfigFactory.parseResources("application.conf")
private lazy val config = ConfigFactory.load()
                          .withFallback(userConfig)
                          .withFallback(environmentConfig)
                          .withFallback(defaultConfig)
                          .resolve()
```

Comment: This should probably be made more clear here https://github.com/typesafehub/config

Comment: There is a problem with this code:  `.resolve()` will pull in values from the environment, but not from system properties.  Not sure how to fix that, yet.

Comment: Found the solution.  Edited the answer to reflect it.

Comment: NOTE: The use of `.load()` in the beginning may make `userConfig` unnecessary in the above code.  But the principle is expressed, and that is the important part.

Comment: You should use `.empty()` instead of `.load()` to make sure `defaultConfig` is used as __fallback__

Comment: I definitely want it to pull in environment variables and system properties.  If I use `.empty()`, will I get that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use `userConfig.withFallback(ConfigFactory.load()).resolve()`, not `ConfigFactory.load().withFallback(userConfig).resolve()`. `parseResources` does not change it for me, the same result (but in this test I don't use references)

Here my tests:

application1.conf

```
app {
  option1 = 323
  common-option = 64
}
```

application2.conf

```
app {
  option2 = 234
  common-option = 32
}
```

```scala
  val conf1 = ConfigFactory.load("application1.conf")
  val conf2 = ConfigFactory.load("application2.conf")

  // 1st variant: there is no option1
  println(conf1.withValue("app", conf2.getValue("app")).resolve().getConfig("app"))
  // {"common-option":32,"option2":234}

  // 2nd variant: common option from config1
  println(conf1.withFallback(conf2).resolve().getConfig("app"))
  // {"common-option":64,"option1":323,"option2":234}

  // 3nd variant: common option from config2
  println(conf2.withFallback(conf1).resolve().getConfig("app"))
  // {"common-option":32,"option1":323,"option2":234}
```

Documentation: https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/main/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/ConfigMergeable.java#L66

```java
     /** ... Again, for details see the spec.
     * 
     * @param other
     *            an object whose keys should be used as fallbacks, if the keys
     *            are not present in this one
     * @return a new object (or the original one, if the fallback doesn't get
     *         used)
     */
    ConfigMergeable withFallback(ConfigMergeable other);
```

Comment: If memory serves, ConfigFactory.load() has the added benefit of populating things from the environment, which is why I do that first.